# Design Question : TTL , Expiration and Pub Sub

Tags: design-patterns, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a requirement where session connects to a user .if user does not respond within 15 seconds and not connected back . The service sends notification to 2nd User from a list. and so on.

To implement this , was trying the redis Key with TTL of 15 seconds. And once it expired , it sends to notification pub-sub. But redis does not guarantee the TTL will trigger the pub sub immediately after expiration. It might have significant delay. Any other suggestions or approach?

https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/

Answer (score 1):

As Redis does not offer exactly-timed notifications, as you have observed, I would suggest to change approach and, instead, rely on a sorted set along with a polling mechanism on the client side, with the score of the entries of the sorted set referring to the last connection timestamp (a Unix time will be okay) of each user.

Something like:

```
ZADD user-list 1668158692 john
```

Then, on the client side, you would poll the sorted set, asking for the entries (the users of your list) which did not connect during the past 15 seconds - that is, whose score lies between *-inf* and the timestamp of 15 seconds ago. The `ZRANGEBYSCORE` command can be used in this case, as shown in the example below:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE user-list -inf 1668158677
```

Should you need to, you can also query the sorted set for the complementary set of users who did connect during the past 15 seconds:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE user-list 1668158677 +inf
```

The polling code on the client side may then just poll Redis every second, asking for the disconnected users.

Comment: But consider the no of events . we are thinking of 10000 such records ..

Comment: The time complexity of `ZADD` is _O(log(N)) for each item added, where N is the number of elements in the sorted set: while the time complexity of `ZRANGEBYSCORE` is _O(log(N)+M) with N being the number of elements in the sorted set and M the number of elements being returned. If M is constant (e.g. always asking for the first 10 elements with LIMIT), you can consider it O(log(N))_. Also the maximum number of items you can store in a sorted set is 2^32-1.